# Delete all items from my queue

Tags: c, queue

I can't delete all my items from my queue. Here is what I am trying to do and here is all my code. Please I can't see what I am doing wrong and also I want to store the count of how many items where in my queue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count = 0;

struct Node
{
    int Data;
    struct Node* next;
}*rear, *front;

void delQueue()
{

    struct Node *var=rear;
    while(var!=NULL)
    {
        free(var);
    var = var->next;
        count = count + 1;

    }

}

void push(int value)
{
    struct Node *temp;
    temp=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->Data=value;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        front=temp;
        front->next=NULL;
        rear=front;
    }
    else
    {
        front->next=temp;
        front=temp;
        front->next=NULL;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct Node *var=rear;
    if(var!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nElements in queue are:  ");
        while(var!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%d",var->Data);
            var=var->next;
        }
    printf("\n");
    } 
    else
    printf("\nQueue is Empty\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

problem is simply here:

```
free(var);
var= var->next;
```

You can do like this:

```
struct Node* buf=var->next;
free(var);
var=buf;
```

Comment: so will that go inside the while loop:

Node* buf=var->next;
free(var);
var=buf;

Comment: I don't inderstand where will those three lines of code go in my program.

Comment: Do you understand where the aforementioned problematic *two* lines are in "your" program ?

Comment: Replace the two line in delQueue fuction

Comment: yes I know where they are, they are in inside my void delQueue(). I'm sry im a little stressed out from this.

Comment: That is not fixing anything it says node its not declared and buf its not declared

Comment: thanks so much, it does work now. but when I delete everything from my queue I can't push anything in anymore

Comment: @user2133160 under what circumstances would push not work? Thinking and stepping through the code in your head helps. You can even use paper and pencil if that helps!

Comment: when I delete all the values from my queue with the help that I got above, the push function does not push new values into the queue it acts as the queue does not exist anymore.

Comment: add two lines at the end of delQueue:
void delQueue()
    {
      ......
      rear = NULL;
      front = NULL;
    }

}